# jQuery ajax - error runs even though it ran successfully

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code as aprt of my .ajax section

```
success: function (data) {
    alert("success");
},
error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
}
```

The first alert never runs, however the data is submitted correctly using the below:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ "solution": JSON.stringify(data) }),  // Data is HTML
```

In fact, the second alert comes back with a status of 200 and everything through Google Chrome console looks fine.

Any idea? Full code:

```
var request = jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/answers/"+content_id,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "solution": data }),
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic XXX',
        'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'PATCH',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         alert(xhr.status);
      }
});
```

Comment: What is the JSON response?

Comment: Check the other arguments to `error`, the second of which is actually `textStatus` according to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). It might be a "timeout", "parseerror" or other built-in error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $.ajax function expects JSON data as response. If the response is not JSON, the error callback will be called. Please have a look at what you are sending out from server.

Comment: application/json is the server response

Comment: Is the server response is valid json data?

Answer (score 0):

Please test some things:

1. Set `type: "GET"` instead of post. Look at this: [GET OR POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376369/get-vs-post-ajax-requests-when-and-how-to-use-either)
2. Headers data are string (name/value), and maybe your data encoding is utf8 so set

   ```
   headers: {

      'Authorization': 'Basic XXX',  //high recommended
      'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'PATCH',
      'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8"  //low
   },
   ```
3. Test another word instead of data to avoid conflict:

   ```
   success: function (response)
   ```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information. Right now this looks more like a set of comments than an actual answer.

Comment: Thanks dear @Mike McCaughan. I Edited my answer.