# how to send two variable from onclick to controller (codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

i get something problem with send two variable to controller:

this my delete button :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger" data-name="<?php echo $data->opsi_color?>" data-id="<?php echo $data->id_opsi_color?>" onclick="hapus_warna(this)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
```

this javascript :

```
function hapus_warna(obj)
{
    var id = $(obj).attr('data-id');
    var name = $(obj).attr('data-name');

    if(confirm('Apa anda yakin ingin menghapus '+name+'?')) {
          // ajax delete data from database
          $.ajax({
            url : baseURL + "trueaccon2194/opsional/warna_dihapuskan/" +id +name,
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
               location.reload();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert('Error deleting data');
            }
        });
     }
}
```

i will send **var id and var name** to controller for I manage
this my controller :

```
function warna_dihapuskan($id,$name){
    $target = $this->input->get('data-name');
    $this->opsional_adm->warna_telah_dihapus($id);
    log_helper("warna", "menghapus warna ".$name."");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
        url : baseURL + "trueaccon2194/opsional/warna_dihapuskan/?id=" +id +"&name="+name,
```

Retrieve the parameters like this in your controller function

```
function warna_dihapuskan(){
    $name = $this->input->get('name');
 $id = $this->input->get('id');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
$.ajax({
        url : baseURL + "trueaccon2194/opsional/warna_dihapuskan/" +id +name,
```

You should send like this

```
$.ajax({
        url : baseURL + "trueaccon2194/opsional/warna_dihapuskan/?data-id=" +id +'&data-name='+name,
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: id
Filename: trueaccon2194/opsional.php
Line Number: 55
Backtrace:
File: D:\xampp\htdocs\starsc\application\controllers\trueaccon2194\opsional.php
Line: 55
Function: _error_handler

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: name
Filename: trueaccon2194/opsional.php
Line Number: 56
Backtrace:
File: D:\xampp\htdocs\starsc\application\controllers\trueaccon2194\opsional.php
Line: 56
Function: _error_handler

Comment: How are you passing $id and $name to warna_dihapuskan($id,$name)?

Comment: I think by sending variable in javascript earlier (+id + name)

Comment: warna_dihapuskan is controller function?

Comment: Instead do warna_dihapuskan() { $id = $this->input->get('data-id'); $name = $this->input->get('data-name'); }

Comment: You can't pass parameters like that.

Comment: how with ID that I can from javascript? if not with a variable name

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying? Could you please be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML write this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger" data-name="<?php echo $data->opsi_color?>" data-id="<?php echo $data->id_opsi_color?>" onclick="hapus_warna(<?php echo $data->id_opsi_color?>,<?php echo $data->opsi_color?>)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
```

and in the function this

```
function hapus_warna(id,name)
{


    if(confirm('Apa anda yakin ingin menghapus '+name+'?')) {
          // ajax delete data from database
          $.ajax({
            url : baseURL + "trueaccon2194/opsional/warna_dihapuskan/" +id+"/" +name,
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
               location.reload();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert('Error deleting data');
            }
        });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really prefer to do

```
method: 'POST'
```

Because then I can just do this inside the $ajax() method:

```
data: {
amount: id,
name: name
}
```

I do believe in this case it would be more interesting to use POST
[GET vs. POST ajax requests: When and how to use either?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376369/get-vs-post-ajax-requests-when-and-how-to-use-either)

and in stead of doing an onclick via inline code it is better to separate it from the view:

```
$(".my_class").on('click', function(){
...
});
```