# GET vs POST in AJAX?

Tags: ajax, http, post, get

Why are there GET and POST requests in AJAX as it does not affect page URL anyway? What difference does it make by passing sensitive data over GET in AJAX as the data is not getting reflected to page URL?

Comment: The data is reflected in the page URL using GET. Have a look at what's happening with a TCP/IP monitor or even just the Header Monitor add-on for Firefox.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715335/get-vs-post-in-ajax/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should use the proper HTTP verb according to what you require from your web service.

---

When dealing with a **Collection** URI like: **`http://example.com/resources/`**

**GET**: List the members of the collection, complete with their member URIs for further navigation. For example, list all the cars for sale.

**PUT**: Meaning defined as "replace the entire collection with another collection".

**POST**: Create a new entry in the collection where the ID is assigned automatically by the collection. The ID created is usually included as part of the data returned by this operation.

**DELETE**: Meaning defined as "delete the entire collection".

---

When dealing with a **Member** URI like: **`http://example.com/resources/7HOU57Y`**

**GET**: Retrieve a representation of the addressed member of the collection expressed in an appropriate MIME type.

**PUT**: Update the addressed member of the collection or create it with the specified ID.

**POST**: Treats the addressed member as a collection in its own right and creates a new subordinate of it.

**DELETE**: Delete the addressed member of the collection.

---

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services)

Comment: Does anyone actually bother with PUT and DELETE?

Comment: "Does anyone actually bother with PUT and DELETE?" -- ever heard of Amazon S3?

Comment: Yes, when defining RESTful web services, you absolutely do.

Answer (score 18):

Well, as for GET, you still have the url length limitation. Other than that, it is quite conceivable that the server treats POST and GET requests differently; thus the need to be able to specify what request you're doing.

Comment: Also, you can use both request types when developing application. For most of them `is_ajax` flag is enough. Better to have such choice then not to have.

Comment: I am accepting dnl.vssll's answer because GET url length limitation is not imposed by HTTP or AJAX, you can check this answer for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string . Its limited by browser/server and why its limited is really a point of discussion .. as HTTP is text based, browser sends HTTP request as a whole.. It includes query string, so if there is no limit on length of request(Assuming ideal case) what is the point in limiting query string ?

Comment: i wasn't making an argument to defend the lenght limit, i was just stating that it was there, and that you'll have to consider it, because when doing web development, you really can't afford to disregard of *browsers*. but hey, you don't need to motivate your accepts; dnl's reply was a good one as well =)

Comment: The length limit is a very valid point in practice as well. I totally agree with David on the "can't afford the disregard of browsers".

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer. We're developers, not Platonic philosophers; you can talk about the ideal Form of the GET - the w3 standard - all you want, but that does not change the fact that when you actually put your application out there in the real world, you have to deal with imperfect browsers which will not correctly handle an arbitrary-length URI.

Answer (score 9):

Another difference between `GET` and `POST` is the way caching is handled in browsers. `POST` response is never cached. `GET` may or may not be cached based on the caching rules specified in your response headers.

Answer (score 6):

Two primary reasons for having them:

1. `GET` requests have some pretty restrictive limitations on size; `POST` are typically capable of containing much more information.
2. The backend may be expecting `GET` or `POST`, depending on how it's designed. We need the flexibility of doing a `GET` if the backend expects one, or a `POST` if that's what it's expecting.

Answer (score 6):

It's simply down to respecting the rules of the http protocol.

**Get** - calls must be idempotent. This means that if you call it multiple times you will get the same result. It is not intended to change the underlying data. You might use this for a search box etc.

**Post** - calls are NOT idempotent. It is allowed to make a change to the underlying data, so might be used in a create method. If you call it multiple times you will create multiple entries.

Answer (score 4):

You normally send parameters to the AJAX script, it returns data based on these parameters. It works just like a form that has method="get" or method="post". When using the GET method, the parameters are passed in the query string. When using POST method, the parameters are sent in the post body.

Generally, if your parameters have very few characters and do not contain sensitive information then you send them via GET method. Sensitive data (e.g. password) or long text (e.g. an 8000 character long bio of a person) are better sent via POST method.

Comment: AFAIK GET and POST methods differ only in their request format, so I don't think POST is more secure than GET. GET is considered insecure because parameters get reflected to url but AJAX overcomes that problem. Also all modern browsers do not limit amount of data we can send via GET request..   .. Only possible explanation I could see from responses is AJAX is designed to exist with well established HTTP protocol.. which is logical.

Comment: @Xinus: Last I heard, both browsers *and* servers still imposed significant URL length (e.g., `GET`) limits, as does the HTTP spec IIRC. Can you post a reference for your statement that they don't?

Comment: You are right. But the reason why some people consider POST to be *slightly* more secure than GET is because GET parameters might get stored in various locations, including server logs and browser history as URLs. POST does not have this issue.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I clarified in David Hedlund's comment

Comment: This was the only answer I was able to comprehend without a bunch of follow up questions in my head. Thank you for the simple clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks..
I mainly use the GET method with Ajax and I haven't got any problems until now except the following:

Internet Explorer (unlike Firefox and Google Chrome) cache GET calling if using the same GET values.

So, using some interval with Ajax GET can show the same results unless you change URL with irrelevant random number usage for each Ajax GET.

Answer (score 0):

Others have covered the main points (context/idempotency, and size), but i'll add another: encryption. If you are using SSL and want to encrypt your input args, you need to use POST.

Comment: This is incorrect. All data transferred over SSL is encrypted. GET vs POST makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: I agree with Joel L. Whole communication is encrypted so where is a question of what method used?

Answer (score 0):

When we use the GET method in Ajax, only the content of the value of the field is sent, not the format in which the content is. For example, content in the text area is just added in the URL in case of the GET method (without a new line character). That is not the case in the POST method.