# How to properly load data from a URL with AJAX in Laravel

Tags: jquery, json, laravel

I want to load the data into the table at the start of the page and after the operations such as create, edit and delete using JQUERY AJAX.

I have CategoryController. In there I have function load() to return JSON data to the view. In blade file, I have ajax function that add new category to the database and it works. What I am getting trouble is loading data from database.

Controller

```
public function load()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        return response()->json($categories);
    }
```

Route

```
Route::get('/categories/load', 'CategoryController@load');
```

JQUERY

```
function loadCategories() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/categories/load",
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data)
                }
            })
        }
```

Category Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between AJAX POST and GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855467/difference-between-ajax-post-and-get)

Comment: You have a post route, you're using a get request.  The route should be a get based on you retrieving data, not changing state.  I recommend you do some reading on post vs get.

Comment: @Devon Thanks for pointing out and suggesting. I have changed to "get" in route but I got no response.

Comment: I doubt it was no response. What was the response's status code?  Was it 200, 500, etc.

Comment: It is 200. @Devon

Comment: A 200 response indicates everything went ok. So you must have gotten some response body even if it was an empty array with this load method.  If it was an empty array then you don't have any categories..

Comment: @devon I got no response, not even an empty array. Perhaps I have some mistakes in returning JSON data in Controller file.

Comment: Did you check if your `$categories` has data ? with `dd()` for example

Comment: Yes I have tested. It has Data. @Saromase

Comment: Try this please : `$categories = Category::all()->toJson();`

Comment: It is not also working

Comment: try to return `return response()->json($categories->toArray());`
If it is that, show https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#serializing-models-and-collections

Comment: Use `Log::info($categories)` to check whether you are getting data from table or not.

Comment: Can I see your model?

Comment: @Saromase it doesn't work

Comment: @Jitendra I will include above

Comment: Share the event from where ajax is firing! May be there is an issue!

Comment: @Iftikharuddin $(document).ready(function(){  loadCategories() })

Comment: @Saromase It works with a POST method. I changed it like I did in add Category function except empty data array.And it returns the object as success callback. But shouldn't it be GET ?

Comment: i dont know, i cant try it now, but in the evening i will try it.

Comment: @Saromase OK.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It should be like that :**

```
//Controller
use App\Category;

...

    public function load()
        {
            return Category::all();
        }
```

Then, basically it's a GET route, so you don't need AJAX at the moment to test it. You can just introduce in browser `localhost:8000/categories/load` and should see the JSON result.