# AJAX - Using POST instead of GET

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Up until now I have been using:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","server_script.php?q="+str,true);
```

Thanks

Edit:
I am providing a solution for anyone that may come across this page to demonstrate how to use POST instead of GET. If you are new to AJAX I would recommend this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_php.asp using the GET method first.

Solution-

javascript:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","script.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send('var_name='+str);
```

php:

```
$var_name = GET['var_name'];

echo $var_name;
```

For reasons regarding the use of POST and GET - see comments blow.

Comment: POST is not more "secure" than GET (apart from not leaving a trace in the history maybe).

Comment: POST should be preferred for queries which change some state on the server. If you are doing a read-only query (as `q=` indicates), then GET is perfectly fine. (The surmised security woes concern CSRF, for which using POST only helps little.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query you show is probably perfectly fine as a GET request. No need to change it.

There are reasons to use one over the other: Requests that change state on server side (i.e. change data) should generally use POST; "read" requests should be GET.

This comes with an implicit security advantage because you can't do any damage by smuggling an URL into a user's page (like, showing an image whose URL points to an admin page named `deleteall.php`).

If your request just retrieves data, you're perfectly fine staying with GET.

See this question for an extensive discussion on when to use which. [GET vs POST in AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872965/get-vs-post-in-ajax)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. However I am using it to edit information.

Comment: @user fair enough, in that case, it makes sense to switch.

Answer (score 7):

this is how you would use post:

```
var url = "server_script.php";
var params = "q="+str;
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

[source](http://openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php)

Comment: Neal, it looks like you copied that over from a Google result again with very little rewriting. Some attribution would be in order. http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php (Also please prefer to type answers on your own.)

Comment: @Neal that is **not** an excuse for quoting without attribution.

Comment: @Pekka, i added the source, and in my last post i also added the source **when i answered the question** and you still complained

Comment: @Neal where did I complain about what? What do you mean?

Comment: sorry @mario did on a previous post that i was copy/pasting info, which i was, and i showed the source and  and @mario still complained

Comment: I'm pretty certain my complaints were about the security issues of your code. (Copy+pasting a 3 liner with bad formatting just does look dull.)