# Get data using POST and AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, get

I'm trying to send some data in my server asynchronously using AJAX.
I need to send the data using the `POST` method because the data sent are quite
many characters and by using `GET` the created URL will be too big. Well that's not a problem, but for aesthetically reasons I would rather have small URLs. In order to do so I used the solution (question) explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638801/ajax-using-post-instead-of-get).

My Javascript code sending the data is:

```
   var code = "code=" + document.getElementById("code_area").value;
   xmlhttp.open("POST", "run_code.php", true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xmlhttp.send(code);
```

The above code is executed when I click a button, but then the URL changes to this:  `localhost/code.php?code=datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata` which seems is no different of using `GET` instead (my URL has become quite big). I used `POST`, not `GET` but still data seems to get transmitted by the URL. Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem after all was that I was using a submit input field in my HTML page like this:

```
<input type="submit" />
```

which when used changed (refreshed) the URL.

By using:

```
<input type="button" />
```

the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that much more easily using jQuery.

```
$.post("run_code.php", { code: $("#code_area").val() });
```

Links:

- [How to add jQuery support to your code](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works).
- [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).
- [$.post() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: @equality.. try with jquery. the 4 lines are reduced to 1.

Comment: Maybe the server is issuing a redirect and since you don't have a custom handler for the response, the browser execute the redirect. Have you tried in different browsers?

Comment: When you say "the URL changes to this" what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Way easier with jquery...

```
$.post( 'yoururlhere.com/phppage',
        {code:$("#code_area").val()},
        function(responseData){
            // responseData is the echo'd data set from your php page
        }, 'json'
);
```

the data within { } are the post K-V pairs

responseData is the dataset echo'd back from php