# Retrieve specific element from external document using AJAX and jQuery .get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Using ajax and jQuery, I'm trying to load content from a specific element in an external document when a user toggles a switch. The target content is dictated by the toggle switch element's `name`.

So I start with HTML...

```
<input id="toggle1" name="externalContent1" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
<input id="toggle2" name="externalContent2" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
<input id="toggle3" name="externalContent3" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
```

I first tried to use '.load()'...

```
$('.toggle').click(function () {

  var section = '#' + $(this).attr('name');

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#target').load("content.htm " + section);
  }

  else {
    $(section).remove();
  }
});
```

This works, but it replaces the content of the `#target` element. I need to append rather than replace.

So then I tried a few suggestions from other SO [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808074/jquery-load-and-append) using `.get()`

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  var content;
  $.get('content.htm ' + section, function(data) {
    content = data;
    $('#target').append(content);
  });
}
```

But these solutions using `.get()`, `.post()`, and `.ajax()` (at least in the way I've tried), don't allow me to specify an element in `content.htm`, it just pulls the whole document.

**Is there a way to use `.get()` to retrieve a specific element from an external document?**

As I've been thinking this through, I suppose I could also search the retrieved page for the `section`, and only append that. I found [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430426/getting-specific-element-from-external-site-using-jquery-ajax), and tried it, but I'm not having any luck with this either:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'content.htm',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
      $(res.responseText).find(section).each(function(){
        $('#target').append($(this).html());
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of hacking, you can use the `.load()` solution. First load into a separate element, then append.

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('<div id="tempForLoad">').load("content.htm " + section, function(){
        $('#target').append($('#tempForLoad').html());
        $('#tempForLoad').remove();
    });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I guess a 'hacky' solution will have to do.
You're missing a `)` in the line `($('#tempForLoad').remove();`
Speaking of that line, why is it wrapped in an extra set of parenthesis? I'm going to give this another day to see if anyone has any other suggestions before marking yours as the answer.

Comment: The open parenthesis was a typo, fixed. That's certainly fine to wait. :)