# How to append the body tag of one html file with another html file

Tags: javascript, html, c#-4.0

I have multiple html files. I want to append the body section of all the html files into one html file.How I can achieve the same by java script code or c# code.

Please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery load() and append](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808074/jquery-load-and-append)

Comment: [This here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483745/replace-html-page-with-contents-retrieved-via-ajax) will probably help you even more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XMLReader to parse the HTML.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx