# AJAX request(delete a comment)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to delete a mysql record with javascript but I fail.

So this is my js function

```
function delpost(id){
    if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
        $('#comment_'+id).hide();
        http.open("get","/index.php?p=delcomment&id=" + id, true);
        http.send();
    }
}
```

And this is my delcomment.php(included through index.php)

```
$comment_id = $_GET['id'];

if(logged() && $status=="administrator"){
    $delquery = mysql_query("DELETE FROM comments WHERE id='$comment_id' LIMIT 1");
    die();
}else{
    die();
}
```

I hope you can help me with this :)

Comment: "I fail" is not enough to go on.  What happens?  Does the AJAX call get made?  Is there an error shown anywhere?  etc.

Comment: Why aren't you using jQuery's ajax methods?

Comment: also, you should not be using the HTTP GET request to delete something. please refer to the following link for the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715335/get-vs-post-in-ajax

Comment: @no.good.at.coding because we dont need jQuery to do ajax.

Comment: Also, SQL injection - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: Are you sure you're logged in as administrator and that you have a mysql database connection? If you have firebug in your browser, it's very useful to select the Net tab & the XHR tab below it. Then, you can see what's happening when you click 'OK'

Comment: @Raynos I'm aware of that. But if you're already loading jQuery, IMO, it usually makes sense to make full of the library instead of working with 'raw' XHR.

Comment: Where are logged() and $status defined?

Comment: @no.goog.at.coding I didnt actually realise that he was using jQuery. Yes he should be using $.ajax

Comment: logged() and $status are defined in index.php

Comment: Want to include the code from there as well?

Comment: And though I'm actually asking questions to help you narrow down the problem, I'm still very concerned about the things you're not asking about, like SQL injection and XSRF prevention. But we'll get to those later.

Comment: might change die() to die(mysql_error()) so we find out what the problem is. echoing what quasistoic wrote, GET should be used to get data from server, POST should be used to send info to server.

Comment: it works when i go to: /index.php?p=delcomment&id=15
but when i click on the link it just hides the comment
(<a href="javascript:;" onclick="delpost(26)">DEL</a>)

Comment: then your http.send isn't working. better use jQuery ajax. like $.post('index.php', {'id':id})

Comment: and in index.php, you'll change $_GET['id'] to $_POST['id'] :)

Comment: Try removing "if(logged() && $status=="administrator")" and check if it works. If yes than You have problem with SESSION (not working) , if not than You have problem sending GET request. Do you use firebug ? Any errors ?Can You trace if GET request is send ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update:
try using

```
http.send(null)
```

instead of

```
http.send()
```

### also, use firebug to see if your ajax request is actually being sent to the server

better solution:
(php rusty!)

delcomment.php

```
$comment_id = $_POST['id'];
$comment_id = mysql_real_escape_string($comment_id);

if(logged() && $status=="administrator"){
    $query = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE id='{$comment_id}'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $con);
     die();
}else{
    die();
}
```

using jquery to post (make sure to include the jquery.js), your javascript function should be like this:

```
function delpost(id){
    if(confirm('Are you sure?')){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/index.php",
            data: {p: "delcomment", id: id},
            success: function(){
                $('#comment_'+id).hide();
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('failure');
            }
        });     
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah,i have a db connection
and there is no error and it works when i go to: /index.php?p=delcomment&id=15 but when i click on the link it just hides the comment (<a href="javascript:;" onclick="delpost(26)">DEL</a>)

Comment: Excellent :) +1 for both. Vote up for him then :D