# Fundamental question in using Jquery with PHP when making ajax calls

Tags: php, jquery, post, get

I have a Fundamental question in using Jquery with PHP when making ajax calls with respect to performance. Is it right to do a Get or a POST. Which is faster when using ajax calls. I know this question has got nothing to do with PHP though, but would like to understand the different view points.

All I am trying to do is to pass variables to PHP and echo data using jquery.

```
$.post('request.php',
   { param1: value, param2:value
   }, function (data) { 
   container.html(data); }


if (isset($_POST['param1']) && isset($_POST['param2'])){

//Do some process on the server
echo "server processed data";
}
```

What is best to use in this case? A `GET` or a `POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance-wise, it doesn't matter. But there are other arguments for one or the other:

[GET vs POST in Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715335/get-vs-post-in-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sending huges amounts of data, you should not be concerned about performance.

This question might also be usefull : [When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)

Comment: I think you screwed up your link there

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The link dont seem to work. Can you please point me to the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

As Pekka says, the performance shouldn't matter.  [RFC 2616, the HTTP 1.1 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) has all the information you need on the standards you should follow about using GET vs. POST.  Short answer is that if you make the same GET request twice in a row, you should get an identical result back.  If you use POST twice in a row, you won't (or you might but there will be another update to the back-end).

Shorter answer is: use GET for retrieval and POST for modification.