# Max Length For Get Variable

Tags: php, get

I was wondering if there is a max length on a $_GET variable. I plan on using ajax with a get command and part of it is an encoding of an access key using one of my encoding methods. This method has returned back roughly 1530 characters and I was wondering if this it too long for a get variable as long as it's all URL encoded?
Thanks in advance,
Spencer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser would greatly affect the max length of your $_GET param

[MAXIMUM LENGTH FOR BROWSERS REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Some versions of PHP have a limitation of length of GET params:

[PHP.NET REFERENCE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php#101469)

Comment: Would I be better to send the AJAX request using post variables? I would assume those can be over 2000 characters

Comment: yes  if you have largeSet of values needed to pass on abd it would be much more reliable also

Comment: heres a link you can decide whats more suitable for you to use dpends on your environment :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715335/get-vs-post-in-ajax

Comment: I take that back, according to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427, in ie at least, the max length for a post variable is also 2,048 characters. Anyways, I'll check into that link. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Max URL length is around 2000 charactors

In IE is around 2048 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7725515/2827152

> Please note that PHP setups with the suhosin patch installed will have a default limit of 512
>   characters for get parameters. Although bad practice, most browsers (including IE) supports URLs up
>   to around 2000 characters, while Apache has a default of 8000.
>
> To add support for long parameters with suhosin, add suhosin.get.max_value_length =  in php.ini

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php#101469