# reload div after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

how i can refresh or reload a div after ajax request? i have this code:

```
function Register(event) {
event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: register,
        data: {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email:   $('#Email').val(),
            password: $('#password').val(),
            _token: $('#token').val()
        },
        dataType : "json",

        success: function (data) {
           if (data.success){

             $('#header').
               $('#Register').modal('hide');

           }
        }
    });

}
```

i need reload or refresh the header div.

Comment: What do you mean by reload? Is it a form?

Comment: Could you please show us your `view` or `html`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ajax success reload div content not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403402/ajax-success-reload-div-content-not-working)

Comment: .ajaxComplete(function( event,request, settings ) {});  works for ajax complete/after ajax

Comment: I want reload a header after login users. Just reload the header.

Comment: Take a look to pushState https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax it is doing what exactly you wish

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can load the div like this.Please mind the space before divid `(" #divid");`

```
if (data.success){
   $("#divid").load(" #divid");
    }
```

Comment: Easy and sweet.

Comment: Your answer just helped me. Thanks. But could you please explain why that space is important? It really doesn't work without it and I just want to know why. Can't find info about that in jquery documentation.

Comment: @Witcher You can learn about *load* function from here http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it saved my time

Comment: This works fine however the text in my div slightly shifts to the left and I am not understanding why is that. Any solutions?

Comment: @rut_0_1 Please remove the style you added for the loading div and add it to the content

Comment: @SreeKS, is this space a bug? Because i really not understand why this happen :b

Comment: I had a matrix of inputs where the border changed according to the value entered which wasn't getting refreshed after an ajax call.  You saved my day with this solution. +1

Comment: I tried this but it did'nt work  
```$('.todo--checkbox').change(function () { let value = $(this).data('value'); $.ajax({ url: `/todo/${value}`, type: 'PUT', data: { done: this.checked }, success: function (data) { if (data.success) { $('#todos').load(location.href + ' #todos'); } }, }); });```

Answer (score 19):

I know this post is old and already answered. But I would Like to add something to it. If you look at the answer of @Sree KS it will load the div on top of the existing div. Which is not ideal. Just run inspect div after the method is completed.

To avoid this issue use the following code:

```
$("#divid").load(" #divid > *");
```

Hope this will help to anyone who has the same issue.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't figure out why there was an additional div until I found this answer.

Comment: Very true. I can confirm that I was able to replicate the aforementioned behavior and the above solution fixed it. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I agree.This is the best option!

Comment: after applying this i can see that the div is not duplicated however the value inside the div is no longer visible unless i reload the page manually, any help as to why?

Comment: Thanks for posting this! Can you explain " > *" 
I'm not finding any information, and it doesn't seem to make any difference. I'm not seeing the div being duplicated without " > *" , as long as the leading space is there.

Comment: It worked but remove all current details from the div. In case I want to only refresh the div content but not empty it. Then what is the best approch?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to reload the header section after login to show the username, logout etc.
To do that you have to return the all html from the your ajax method into the "data.success" variable using like json encode.

```
your ajax method function () {
    $response = array('success' => 'Your html data come here');
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I want only reload. The username, etc. I use php for show.

Comment: and in ajax call
success: function (data) {
   if (data.success){
  $('#header').html(data.success);
   }
}